# Collection instance on point Geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, collections

I'm beggining with the geometry node by trying to distribute collection of trees on a plane.
When i'm using the whole collection it distribute it with the original position as one object.
[image]
I tried to use the separate geometry node but the whole collection dispear.
[image]
What is the right way to get separated object from the collection on each point?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All these checkboxes should be checked:

[image]

Comment: I just tried it doesn't do anything

Comment: @a33 In addition to the answer shown, try removing the `Separate Components` node. The instances are already separated as soon as you have activated *Separate Children*.

Comment: It fix it ! Thanks a lot !